# Having issues with transparent textures

Tags: uv, transparency

I have a problem with the transparency of my model, I tried many ways but I can't get the black part to go away

[image]

[image]

[image]

here you have the model and textures

[image]

Comment: Try changing your blend mode to alpha-blend - if you want to stick with alpha-clip, you might need to adjust the clip threshold.

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: here you have https://blend-exchange.com/b/QmWRBJzJ